# MongoDB service not starting on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mongodb

[image: The unit file for mongoDB doestnt exist]I have installed the update version of mongoDB on ubuntu 22.04 following the [instructions on the official documentaion](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/installing-mongodb-over-ubuntu-22-04/159931)

I have installed all the dependencies which were missing on the latest ubuntu 22.04 (  libssl1.1 )

After adding the right file and config file in system I cant start mongoDB service with this command

```
sudo systemctl enable mongodb

sudo service mongodb start
```

Comment: This might be an issue of database folder ownership!! Try this: create a folder in your home directory naming whatever you like. For eg. database and run `mongod --dbpath ~/database` And can you show your logs also!! It will be more helpful!

Comment: Please share more details. How is this problem related to Mongoose or [tag:node-modules]?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: @NicoHaase why do you think **starting MongoDB** is related to Mongoose or node-modules?

Comment: @RosanPaudel creating the data folder in your home directory is maybe not the best choice, esp. when the MongoDB runs under `mongod` user.

Comment: The **official** documentation is this one: [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Ubuntu](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: I am not an expert, but I think you should not mix *systemd* (`systemctl`) and *System V Init* (`service`)

Answer (score -1):

**After hours of trial, the following method worked for me!**

The problem, "Unit File Mongod.Service Does Not Exist" ma be solved by enabling the service `sudo systemctl enable mongodb.service` or `systemctl enable mongodb.service`

But, this works if the file *mongodb.service* is already in our system.

Check your system if it has the *mongodb.service* file with this command

```
systemctl list-unit-files --type=service
```

If you get that "mongodb.service   disabled" then you are ready to enable it. BUt if you didn't see anything like that you should create the "mongo.service" file.

**Let's create a file.**

#### Navigate to the systems

```
 cd /lib/systemd/system
```

#### Create a file using touch command

```
sudo touch mongod.service
```

#### Edit the file you created using your favorite shell editor. let's use VIM

```
sudo vim mongod.service
```

*Then write the following lines in your mongo.service file.*

```
[Unit]
Description=An object/document-oriented database
Documentation=man:mongod(1)
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongodb.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

NOW, save and exit from your file.

**Hurrah, you have fixed the problem!**

Comment: Usually the service file is created at installation. However it is named `mongod.service` (not `mongodb.service`), have a careful look. You should not install custom service files at `/lib/systemd/system`, they might be overwritten when you update the package. Better use `/etc/systemd/system`, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206315/whats-the-difference-between-usr-lib-systemd-system-and-etc-systemd-system